# Tag a is not clickable in safari

Tags: html, safari

I have a problem with the tag `<a>` in safari, is not clickable. I mean when I code like this:

`<a href="www.example.com">Link</a>`

it's working well (it totally works with using words), but when I use:

```
<a href="www.example.com">
    <i class="ico-icon"></i>
</a>
```

it won't be clickable and I can't understand why is not working? can anyone help me to find out what is going on between safari and `<a>`? Thanks.

Comment: 1. Do you really need to use the i tag? If all you want is to have a clickable icon then there are other ways to do that. 2. Why use an i tag for an icon? Seems like mis-use of italics.

Answer (score -1):

According to W3C.com, the i tag is suposed to be used in text when you want to make the text "italic". Like this:

```
<p>He named his car <i>The lightning</i>, because it was very fast.</p>
```

Read more here:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp

And if I were you, i would use an img tag instead so that it would look something like this:

```
<a href="www.example.com">
    <img src="ico-icon" alt="icon">
</a>
```

So, the reason to why its not working is becouse you are using the i tag wrong.